# Запись из csv файла в словарь Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

В csv файле хранится список смежности графа в виде, где на первом месте стоит номер вершины, а всё что идёт после этого в строке - вершины, которые с ней связаны
[image: список смежности]

Как считать данные из файла в словарь, чтобы в итоге ключом был номер вершины, а значениями были вершины, которые с ней связаны?

Comment: Забыл сказать, что каждая вершина хранится в отдельной ячейке

Comment: Пример CSV покажете?

Comment: А в чём именно вопрос? Считываете построчно, режете строки по табу, приводите всё к интам и раскладываете в словарь. Хоть в цикле, хоть через dict comprehension. Что именно вызвало затруднение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821690/create-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file-in-python-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, значения в CSV разделены запятыми:

```
import csv 


with open('sample.csv') as f:
    graph = {line[0]:line[1:] for line in csv.reader(f)}

print(graph)

# {'1': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], '2': ['4', '5', '3', '6', '2', '1', '6', '2'], '3': ['5', '6', '2', '5', '6', '2']}
```